# Why is Javascript not working with Django HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am trying to put some javascript code in my Django website. The javascript code is supposed to check if the buttons are being pressed and alert the user if they are. This only works for the first button, however. Because I am looping over all the buttons to display them, I think javascript is not seeing it as HTML code. Here is the javascript code.

```
const card = document.querySelector('.card');

card.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('btn')) {
    alert('hi')
  }
})
```

Here is the HTML/Django code :

```
{% extends "/Users/marco/Documents/codes/Python/Django/vracenmasse/templates/base_generic.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

    <center><h1>Nos Produits</h1></center>
    <hr>

    <div class="row" style = "border: 50px solid white;">

            {% for product in products %}

                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="../../../media/{{ product.product_picture.name }}" alt="{{ product.product_picture.name }}">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <center>
                            <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.name }}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">{{ product.product_price|floatformat:2 }}$ / unité</p>
                            <p class="card-text">Catégorie : {{ product.type_of_product }}</p>
                            {% if product.new_product == "yes" %}
                                <b><p class="card-text"><font size="3.5" color="Orange">Nouveaux!</font></p></b>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% if product.availability == "Out Of Stock"%}
                                <b><p class="card-text"><font size="1.5" color="red">En rupture de stock</font></p></b>
                                <hr>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Ajouter au Panier</button>
                            {% else %}
                                <p style="font-size:15;">Quantité : </p><input type="number" step="12" min="0" />
                                <span class="validity"></span>
                                <hr>

                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id='realbutton'>Ajouter au Panier</button>

                            {% endif %}

                            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert" style ="visibility:hidden;">
                              <center>Produit ajouté au panier!</center><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                              </button>
                            </div>


                        </center>
                  </div>
                </div>  
                &nbsp;
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
</div>


<script src="{% static "products/buttonalerts.js" %}"></script>  
{% endblock %}
```

The first button is the only thing that works. We can see on line #6 there is the for loop. It iterates over all the products and it adds its own "Add To Cart" Button. The alert only works for the first button though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating a “div” element for each product in your list, but the querySelector() method only returns the first element with the specified class.

You need to use the querySelectorAll() method to get a list with all the elements then apply the event listener to each of them:

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    cards[i].addEventListener('click', e => {
        if (e.target.classList.contains('btn')) {
            alert('hi')
        }
    }
)
```

Another solution would be to query directly for the elements that contain the “btn” class and add the event listener to those:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {                  
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert('hi');
    }
)
```